# Displaying Another View in ASP.Net Web API Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

New to the world of Web API and I can't seem to get any custom view to display. I've done the basics, made a method in my controller that seems to be linked corrected where I'm calling it. I'm more familiar with MVC so I'm wondering am I missing something basic here? The view always returns an error can't be accessed for me.

The ActionResult, in the generated HomeController:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SpotDetails()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Spot Details";
    return View();
}
```

The link to call it in the menu:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("SHOR //", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, null)</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, null)</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Spot Profile", "SpotDetails", "Home", new {area = ""}, null)</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new {area = ""}, null)</li>
</ul>
```

I should say the links to the index and the api help pages work perfectly.

This is my RouteConfig in case it's at fault, I haven't touched it at all:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And finally my WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
        Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Edit - the error message when the link is clicked:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its >dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily >unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled >correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Home/SpotDetails

Comment: What are the details of the error?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added the exact error

Comment: Looks good to me. You sure that SpotDetails.cshtml is in /Views/Home/ and it is spelled exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is an issue with your startup configuration. Routes must be registered in order from most specific to least specific. You have accounted for that within your `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` and `WebApiConfig.Register` methods. However, you must also call `WebApiConfig.Register` before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` or your `Default` route will take precedence over any of the Web API routes.

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```